# "colspam" in my sql select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select that gives me the following result:

```
 School name           teacher name
-----------------------------------
 school1         -     teacher1
 school1         -     teacher2
 school1         -     teacher3

 school2         -     teacher2
 school2         -     teacher4
 school2         -     teacher5

 school3         -     teacher2
 school3         -     teacher4
 school3         -     teacher1
```

And I want something like this:

```
 School name           teacher name
-----------------------------------
 school1         -     teacher1
                 -     teacher2
                 -     teacher3

 school2         -     teacher2
                 -     teacher4
                 -     teacher5

 school3         -     teacher2
                 -     teacher4
                 -     teacher1
```

How can I do this in sql server?
Thanks!

Comment: This is really more of a formatting issue which should be left to the front end. If you really must do it in sql the answer will depend on which version of sql server you are using. And this would be rowspan, not colspan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sean say, its not a best way to burden *sql server* with formatting issue, so consider to leave it to reporting service.. But if you really want to do it by any mean necessary then use this code:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN First_Name = Teacher_Name THEN A.School_Name ELSE '' END School_Name, 
    Teacher_Name 
FROM
    Table1 A INNER JOIN
    (SELECT School_Name, MIN(Teacher_Name) First_Name FROM Table1
        GROUP BY School_Name) B
    ON A.School_Name = B.School_Name
ORDER BY
    A.School_Name
```

NOTE: the code is untested on the given schema, please let me know if something wrong